# Typescript paths imports not working as default

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, import

I'm trying to make default import in `.ts` files using the paths that are configured in my `tsconfig.base.json` (which is defined as default in the File Type > Typescript Config)

[image: Imports statement]

The one I'm would like to be used here is the one from the bottom : TS Import '...' from module "@Dashboard...", but when I use "Add import statement" it gives me only the relative or absolute import plus the one from my dependencies and not the @dashboard one.

I tried a lot of research and different configuration without success, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my mistake !

My "paths" configuration was included in a tsconfig.base.ts file which was extended by the referenced tsconfig files in the intellij configuration.

Intellij is not resolving it, we have to manually add this file in the "File Types > Typscript config" configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Emilien's own answer is still relevant in 2024 as vue3 creates tsconfig.node.json and tsconfig.vitest.json, both of which are not in the Editor > File Types > TypeScript config > File name patterns. So Intellij never reads their values. So imports from a tests reference will not get their url shortened by IntelliJ.

In short: In IntelliJ and other JetBrains products add all your tsconfig.*.json files to Settings > Editor > File Types > TypeScript config > File name patterns.